# Cake PHP delete by custom field

Tags: php, database, cakephp

I got table Categories and i wanna delete record by id_category. What I'm doing wrong ?

index.ctp:

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->postLink(
    'Delete',
    array('action' => 'delete', $categories['Category']['id_category']),
        array('confirm' => 'Are you sure?')
    );
?>
```

CategoriesController:

```
public function delete($id) {
    if ($this->request->is('get')) {
        throw new MethodNotAllowedException();
    }

    $categories = $this->Category->findById_Category($id);
    $this->Category->delete($categories['Category']['id_category']);
}
?>
```

Comment: That looks suspiciously like ... `id_category` is the primary key. In which case the find is unnecessary, you can just call `$this->Category->delete($id)`. It's necessary to tell CakePHP the [name of the primary key](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#primarykey) if you're not following conventions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

findById_Category() is not a valid magic finder.

As documented You need to use proper camel cased format:

```
findByIdCategory()
```

But personally, I would not use magic finders. I would use a normal find(first) call instead.

And don't call your variable `$categories` when you expect a single result. It is confusing.

And last but not least also note that "id_category" is highly unconventional. If there is no reason for it, don't strive from the conventions, in this case "category_id" for the field name of a foreign key to Category model / categories table.

**EDIT**
The above comment led me to believe that here your unconventionel "id_category" field is actually supposed to be the primary key of that table. Which would make your find call actually even incorrect as in that case you should have used the (linked) documentation to map that field properly as your primary key:

```
public $primaryKey = 'id_category';
```

But here the same thing is true, as well: If there is no sane reason for it, don't use "id_category" but "id".

Either way you can then directly use

```
$this->Category->delete($id);
```

Also, when looking for a record:

```
$this->Category->findById($id); // No matter what the field actually is named
```

And for saving:

```
$this->Category->save($data);
$id = $this->Category->id; // It will always map to `->id` internally.
```

Docs: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#primarykey